# Data is being filled on both of the rows while using ajax. But I want to run ajax call separately for each row

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to run the Ajax function for each row separately. But with the given code the function is being run on both the rows even if I select category only on the first row.

the table will have new rows added and removed with a button, so can't give the select different class.

**This is the HTML with PHP within it.**

```
<table  class="center" id="Cateogry">
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Item</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="form-group">
                               <label for="CATEGORY-DROPDOWN">Category</label>
                               <select class="form-control category-dropdown">
                                  <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                  <?php
                                     require_once "../config.php";
                                     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menu_category where outlet_id = 18");
                                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                     ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $row["category_name"];?></option>
                                  <?php
                                     }
                                     ?>
                               </select>
                            </div></td>
        <td style="width:30%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SUBCATEGORY">Sub Category</label>
            <select class="form-control sub-category-dropdown">
            </select>
         </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Item</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="form-group">
                               <label for="CATEGORY-DROPDOWN">Category</label>
                               <select class="form-control category-dropdown">
                                  <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                  <?php
                                     require_once "../config.php";
                                     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menu_category where outlet_id = 18");
                                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                     ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $row["category_name"];?></option>
                                  <?php
                                     }
                                     ?>
                               </select>
                            </div></td>
        <td style="width:30%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SUBCATEGORY">Sub Category</label>
            <select class="form-control sub-category-dropdown">
            </select>
         </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**This is the Script**

```
<script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.category-dropdown').on('change', function() {
            var category_id = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "fetch-subcategory-by-category.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    category_id: category_id
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $(".sub-category-dropdown").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
          </script>
```

Comment: Both `select` share the same classname -> `sub-category-dropdown`. Then of course `$(".sub-category-dropdown").html(result);` will update both of them. You might want to switch to ID's instead.

Comment: @GuidoFaecke no, especially in a situation like this, you'd rather want to avoid using IDs. Identifying the correct elements to address based on their relation to other elements in the DOM structure makes much more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the select that corresponds to the one in the row. So look for the table row and find the select in it.

```
$('.category-dropdown').on('change', function() {
  const subSelect = $(this).closest("tr").find(".sub-category-dropdown"); 
  ...
```